# How to put a Google login on my main login form as an option?

Tags: google-api, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I just want to put an Google login on my main form login as an Alternative way of logging in to the Mob app that i was developing.I want on my main fomr to have a (Login with Google) but i dont have any idea how to do it. is there anyone can help me? this is only for educational purposes, i just want to enhance my programming skills.

I tried searching and Firebase auth always appears.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth is actually free to use for the auth section so it's not a bad option.

There are a lot of moving parts with this and learning by using Firebase as your core is a great way to get introduced without handling so much of the complications. If this is just for education my personal recommendation would be to learn Firebase methods first and then look into replacing it with your own implementation.

However, if you want to just use Google Auth using a native plugin and nothing else then there is a tutorial on IonicThemes.com which covers how to set it up.

You can read it here if you're fast:

- https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-google-login

This question will probably get deleted as it doesn't meet the guidelines to just post links to tutorials, but it's a lengthy process so I don't know what else StackOverflow expects me to offer in this instance. Perhaps just to vote to close your question.